# Adding column which groups data by time

Tags: sql-server, grouping, datediff

I've got a table which shows: `Power`, `Time`, `Diff-Days`, `Diff-Hours`, `Diff-Minutes` where the diff columns use `datediff` and `lag` to calculate the difference in times between the rows.

```
(PowerkW) (Time)               (Diff-Days) (Diff-Hours) (Diff-Minutes)   
 31011.39  2014-01-01 00:30:00  NULL        NULL         NULL  
 31838.74  2014-01-01 00:40:00  0           0            -10  
 32356.35  2014-01-01 00:50:00  0           0            -10  
 32358.82  2014-01-01 01:00:00  0           -1           -10  
 32414.15  2014-01-01 01:10:00  0           0            -10  
 32413.81  2014-01-01 01:20:00  0           0            -10  
 32412.35  2014-01-01 01:30:00  0           0            -10  
 32416.23  2014-01-01 01:40:00  0           0            -10  
 32014.94  2014-01-01 01:50:00  0           0            -10  
 31184.45  2014-01-01 03:40:00  0           -2           -110  
 32403.38  2014-01-01 03:50:00  0           0            -10  
 32415.07  2014-01-01 04:00:00  0           -1           -10  
 32388.04  2014-01-01 04:10:00  0           0            -10  
 32320.70  2014-01-01 04:20:00  0           0            -10  
 32297.44  2014-01-01 04:30:00  0           0            -10
```

What I want is a 6th column which groups these rows into events which are happening consecutively, i.e 9 happening every 1 minutes one after the other would have 1 in the 6th column then there could be a 2 hour difference and then 6 rows happening after each other which could have 2 in the 6th column, is this possible?
i.e.

```
(PowerkW) (Time)               (Diff-Days) (Diff-Hours) (Diff-Minutes) (Group)  
 31011.39  2014-01-01 00:30:00  NULL        NULL         NULL           1  
 31838.74  2014-01-01 00:40:00  0           0            -10            1             
 32356.35  2014-01-01 00:50:00  0           0            -10            1             
 32358.82  2014-01-01 01:00:00  0           -1           -10            1  
 32414.15  2014-01-01 01:10:00  0           0            -10            1 
 32413.81  2014-01-01 01:20:00  0           0            -10            1  
 32412.35  2014-01-01 01:30:00  0           0            -10            1  
 32416.23  2014-01-01 01:40:00  0           0            -10            1  
 32014.94  2014-01-01 01:50:00  0           0            -10            1  
 31184.45  2014-01-01 03:40:00  0           -2           -110           2  
 32403.38  2014-01-01 03:50:00  0           0            -10            2  
 32415.07  2014-01-01 04:00:00  0           -1           -10            2  
 32388.04  2014-01-01 04:10:00  0           0            -10            2  
 32320.70  2014-01-01 04:20:00  0           0            -10            2  
 32297.44  2014-01-01 04:30:00  0           0            -10            2
```

Comment: What is your definition of "consecutive"?

Comment: Are -10 and -110 only possible values for (Diff-Minutes)?

Comment: the data is recorded every 10 minutes, there are other values too but they're all multiples of 10

Comment: consecutive as in 10 mins after the previous entry

Comment: OK, so you need to increase value in the Group column if the gap is over 10 mins? Use Gordon's answer, just change -50 to -10. And add an ORDER BY :)

Answer (score 1):

If your definition of consecutive is based on the "diff minutes" being greater than some value (or less than, given that these are negative), then you can use a cumulative sum:

```
with q as (<your query here>)
select q.*,
       sum(case when diff_minutes < -50 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by time) as grp
from q;
```

If you really want to start at "1", then just add one to the value.